# React-Navigation back from child to specific parent

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I'm developing project, using react-navigation with redux. The issue is when i'm on DrawerNav (Home) and going to the PatientRecordNavigation -> Menu, but when press the back button, the action not back from PatientRecordNavigation (Menu) to  -> Home, but to the ChooseAnimal, I don't want to the going to the ChooseAnimal, but need going to the Home (like on the browserhistory, always back to the previous navigation).
The back button located on the header with dispatch function to the reducer

```
const DrawerNav = DrawerNavigator({
    Home: {screen: Home},
    Records: { screen: PatientRecordNavigation }
},
{
  initialRouteName: "Home"
});

const PatientRecordNavigation = StackNavigator(
{
    ChooseAnimal: { screen: ChooseAnimal },
    Menu: { screen:Menu },
    Reminders: { screen: Reminders }   
},
{
    initialRouteName: "ChooseAnimal",
    headerMode: 'none'
});
```

part of navigation reducer

```
 case 'BACK':
        nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(NavigationActions.back(), state);
    break;
```

Please help, to resolve this issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `key` to the `NavigationActions.back()` as described [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions#Back). You can get the key of the current view in the navigation state. If that doesn't work, try passing `{key: null}`.

Comment: it's won't work, still back to the ChooseAnimal not to the home menu.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your reducer, have a case for `Menu`. Configure the back button push the action for `Menu` when pressed.

```
case 'MENU':
    nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(
            NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: Screens.Menu})
        );
break;
```

Back button configuration

```
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native'
 ...
 ...

 componentWillMount() {
    this.backButtonListener = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
        this.context.props.navigation.dispatch({ type: 'MENU' });
        return true;
    }); 
}

 componentWillUnmount() {
    this.backButtonListener.remove();
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm solved this arbitrary route by adding type on reducer.
when I'm from Home -> Menu, I'm call RECORD_HOME
when I'm from ChooseAnimal -> Menu, I'm call RECORD

So, the solution is playing with navigation reset, when I'm won't back to ChooseAnimal, I will change (with reset function) the initialRouteName

Example code:

```
const initialState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(
   NavigationActions.init()
);
const navReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
     let nextState;
     switch(action.type){
        case 'RECORD_HOME':
          nextState = changeInitialRoute('Menu', state, {animal: action.payload, parentKey: state.key})
        break;
        case 'RECORD':
          nextState = defineRoute('Menu', state, {animal: action.payload, parentKey: state.key})
        break;
        default:
          nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state)
        break;
     }
    return nextState || state;
}

const changeInitialRoute = (routeName, state, params = null) =>{
   let action = NavigationActions.reset({
      index:0,
      actions:[NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: routeName, params: params})]
    })
   return(
    AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state)
   );
 }

 const defineRoute = (routeName, state, params = null) =>{
  let action = NavigationActions.navigate({ 
    routeName: routeName,
    params: params
  });
  return(
    AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state)
  );
}
```